# jQuery get the total position from an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I want to set the focus position on a variable #id after an Ajax reloads the content within a container. The container itself has `overflow:auto;` in it so I get to see a scrollbar if the content is too large. But after inserting new content, I can't get the focus set on the #id I'm giving it to set on.

I first tried to set the focus on the ID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetFocus(ulID) {
  var HeightUL = $("#"+ulID).offset();
  $("#"+ulID).focus();
}
</script>
```

Later I tried to get the total height of this ID, so I could put an `offset()` on it, with `$("#"+ulID).offset().top;` or `$("#"+ulID).position().top;`.

```
function SetFocus(ulID) {
  var HeightUL = $("#"+ulID).offset().top;
  $("#"+ulID).stop().animate({ scrollTop: HeightUL }, 'fast');
}
```

But this isn't working either. With `position()` I get 0 in return and with `offset()` it only returns the object's height relative to its parent. And not the total height where the object is positioned within its container.

The HTML:

```
<div class="info-container edit" id="info-container-edit">
  <span class="cat">Info 1</span>
  <ul id="Info1" class="cat-list music">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="cat cat">Info 2</span>
  <ul id="Info2" class="cat-list music">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="cat cat">Info 3</span>
  <ul id="Info3" class="cat-list music">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="cat cat">Info 4</span>
  <ul id="Info4" class="cat-list music">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The Ajax code refreshes the container `#info-container-edit`. My problem is for example I want to focus on `#Info3` with `SetFocus('Info3');`. It seems that it returns the height of `#Info2` and not the total height from the container `#info-container-edit` till `#Info3`.

Can anybody point out how to fix this problem? If I can get the position height of an #id within its container, I should get the problem fixed. Or how to set the display focus on the #id?

Comment: Where are you calling `SetFocus()`?

Comment: After the Ajax success. I do know that to get the height I should first store the height position before the ajax handeling and when I have a ajax success, I then use this height for the scrollTop. But first I need to get the proper height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView):

```
document.getElementById(ulID).scrollIntoView(false);
```

Comment: Also not working, I get the error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null I think it is because I rebuild the whole info-container-edit content with Ajax, so after the build the element ID is gone.

Comment: @Flyhnl Well, then what element do you want to scroll into view?

Comment: Got it working now! I noticed that it did scroll to the right element when I put a alert before it. Just for testing if I had the right elementname. After that I looked better on the success state and made a better trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop($('#Info2').offset().top);
});
```

see it working [at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Am4Rn/)